# If $u = 0$ on $\partial U$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial N} = 0$ on $\partial U$, then $\nabla u = 0$ on $\partial U$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Suppose that $u$ is a smooth function from an open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with smooth boundary to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $N$ be the (outward) normal on $\partial U$.

If we know that $$u = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial N}:= \nabla u \cdot N = 0 \qquad \text{on} \qquad \partial U,$$ can we then deduce that $\nabla u = 0$ on $\partial U$?

I came accross this problem when studying a PDE. I tried to play around with integral equations, but it didn't really get me anywhere. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I read somewhere that $u=0$ on $\partial U$ implies that $\nabla u$ and $N$ are parallel on $\partial U$. But I don't know why this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you remember is correct. Indeed, if the the boundary is smooth you can parametrize it with a smooth curve, say $s:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. (I'll be considering $\nabla u$ only on the boundary, even if I won't write it explicitly).
Let's call $v(t) = u(s(t))$. Now $v\equiv0$, because $u$ is $0$ on the boundary. Thus $\dot{v} \equiv0$. Computing the derivative we get $$\dot{v}(t)= \nabla u(s(t))\cdot \dot{s}(t).$$ Recall that the vector $\dot{s}(t)$ lives in the tangent space to the curve in $s(t)$. This means that the projection of $\nabla u(t)$ to the tangent space is $0$ (for every $t$) and it allows us to conclude that if $\nabla u(t)$ has a nonzero component, this must be in the same direction of $N_{s(t)}$ (the normal to the surface in $s(t)$).

Comment: Very nice! But the derivative of $v$ is $\dot{v} = \nabla u (s(t)) \cdot \dot{s}(t)$ right?

Comment: Sorry for being sloppy! You are definitely right!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the unit disc $U = \{ (r,\theta): r\leq 1 \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.

Then $\partial_N u = \partial_r u = 0$, so $\nabla u = \begin{pmatrix} \partial_r u \\ \partial_\theta u \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \partial_\theta u \end{pmatrix}$.

But $u \equiv 0$ on $\partial U = \mathbb{S}^1$, so $u(1,\phi) = u(1,\psi) = 0$ for all $\phi,\psi$, and so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}(1,\phi) = 0$ for all $\phi$. So what you recall seems correct in this case, and I think in general.

Basically if $u \equiv 0$ on $\partial U$, then the projection of the gradient onto the boundary is necessarily zero, leaving only the normal component.